# How to delete QWidget after QMdiSubWindow was closed

Tags: c++, qt

I have a pointer of QWidget subclass:

`QWidget * form;`

Next I put the instance of the subclass as an internal widget of QMdiSubWindow:

`QMdiSubWindow * w = mdiArea->addSubWindow(form);`

How to make sure that the object `form` is deleted when the MDI subwindow `w` is closed?

Comment: You might set the `Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose` attribute to your MDI sub window like `w->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);`

Comment: @vahancho It seems to me that this case the subwindow itself is deleted, but not the widget inside it.

Comment: The internal widget will be deleted automatically, I guess, because of it's parent-child relationship with MDI window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/QMdiArea.html#addSubWindow) you must set the `Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose` flag on the subwindow so it will be automatically deleted after it is closed.

Back to your actual question: when you call `addSubWindow` it calls [`setWidget`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmdisubwindow.html#setWidget) internally. After that step the passed widget's parent is the `QMdiSubWindow` object on which the call was made. Hence, after that object gets deleted it will also delete all its children, including the said widget, as [almost] any dutiful Qt object does.